# WFS filter for property name

Tags: wfs, web-mapping, gml

I need help with WFS filtering for GML. I want to filter only by one property (name of administrative unit) - that is all.

Lets say I would like to get the second member of this GML:
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit&count=2

The name of administrative unit is in this tag: `<gn:text>Hlavní město Praha</gn:text>` (path: au:name > gn:GeographicalName > gn:spelling > gn:SpellingOfName > gn:text)

Here are some of my tests which do not work:

```
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit&FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>gn:text</ValueReference><Literal>Hlavní město Praha</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>
```

When I use ogr2ogr to transform the GML to GeoJSON (the WFS returns only GML) then the name of the administrative unit is in "text" attribute.

```
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit&FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>text</PropertyName><Literal>Hlavní město Praha</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>
```

This one returns whole layer instead of the 1 feature/member:

```
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit&CQL_FILTER=text='Hlavní město Praha'
```

Here is meta for the layer & service:

http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit

http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

Any idea how to filter the nested tags in GML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WFS 2.0 you can use a [*limited* set of XPath](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html#37) to specify your property in the feature so in your case a query like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd         http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeNames="au:AdministrativeUnit">
    <fes:Filter>
      <PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ValueReference>name/GeographicalName/spelling/SpellingOfName/text</ValueReference>
        <Literal>Hlavní město Praha</Literal>
      </PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

But this server (despite claiming to support POST in the getCapabilities) doesn't seem to like POSTed queries so you need to URL encode the Filter which should give you a URL like:

```
"http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=au:AdministrativeUnit&FILTER=%3Cfes%3AFilter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CValueReference%3Ename%2FGeographicalName%2Fspelling%2FSpellingOfName%2Ftext%3C%2FValueReference%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CLiteral%3EHlavn%C3%AD%20m%C4%9Bsto%20Praha%3C%2FLiteral%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ffes%3AFilter%3E%0D%0A"
```

But all I can get from that is an `OperationProcessingFailed` error, so something seems to be up with either my request or the server.

Since it seems to not be a GeoServer you almost certainly can't use CQL_FILTERs anyway.

Comment: I found out that the WFS server has stored queries so I used it: http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-au-wfs.asp?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=GetUnitByName&UNIT_NAME=Hlavn%C3%AD%20m%C4%9Bsto%20Praha&NAT_LEVEL=Kraj

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in

```
https://inspire-wfs.maanmittauslaitos.fi/inspire-wfs/au/wfs.
```

I tried to proposed solution, but the server returned an error.
I modified the query a bit and got a correct result with this query:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetFeature 
    service="WFS"
    version="2.0.0"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"
    xmlns:au="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0"
    xmlns:gn="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/gn/4.0"
>
<Query typeNames="au:AdministrativeUnit" srsName="EPSG:4326">
    <fes:Filter>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:ValueReference>au:name/gn:GeographicalName/gn:spelling/gn:SpellingOfName/gn:text</fes:ValueReference>
           <fes:Literal>Helsinki</fes:Literal>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </fes:Filter>
</Query>
```